# Custom notice is not working on Woocommerce My-account custom endpoint page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, endpoint

I have been working on creating an error code that is for WooCommerce "My account" page. I have also successfully added a WooCommerce end point to this custom page, however, when I try using the composite hook `"woocommerce_add_{$notice_type}"` it wouldn't work on the custom page, but would work on the base WooCommerce endpoints like my-account.

Custom my-account page Registration (named *edit-password*):

```php
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'silva_log_history_link', 40 );
function silva_log_history_link( $menu_links ){
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 5, true ) 
    + array( 'edit-password' => 'Edit Password' )
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 5, NULL, true );
     
    return $menu_links;
}

add_action( 'init', 'silva_add_endpoint' );
function silva_add_endpoint() {
    // WP_Rewrite is my Achilles' heel, so please do not ask me for detailed explanation
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'edit-password', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_edit-password_endpoint', 'silva_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function silva_my_account_endpoint_content() {
    #some code for separation
}
```

Custom Error Code:

```php
function custom_wc_add_notice( $message ){
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) ){
        global $woocommerce;
        extract( $_POST );
            
        $message .= ' Your custom message';
    }
    return $message;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_success', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
```

Another thing is that when i change the error code to edit-password, it doesn't seem to work but when i use the my-account page the changes seem to work. Thanks, hoping to get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing function that need to be hooked in `woocommerce_get_query_vars` filter hook, to be able to use `is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-password')` conditional function with your custom endpoint.

Try the following code replacement *(I have renamed your functions)*:

```php
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_my_account_edit_password_menu_item', 40 );
function add_my_account_edit_password_menu_item( $menu_links ){
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 5, true ) 
    + array( 'edit-password' => __('Edit Password', 'woocommerce') )
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 5, NULL, true );
     
    return $menu_links;
}

// HERE is the missing hooked function
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'define_edit_password_query_var' );
function define_edit_password_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['edit-password']  = 'edit-password';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_edit-password_endpoint', 'add_edit_password_endpoint_content' );
function add_edit_password_endpoint_content() {
    ## The Edit pasword page content

    // For testing we print directly an error message
    wc_print_notice('This is an error message…', 'error');
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_edit_password_rewrite_endpoint' );
function add_edit_password_rewrite_endpoint() {
    // WP_Rewrite is my Achilles' heel, so please do not ask me for detailed explanation
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'edit-password', EP_PAGES );
}
```

Don't forget to Flush WordPress rewrite rules, by going to general Settings > Permalinks and click on "Save Changes".

Now, if you use `is_wc_endpoint_url('edit-password')` conditional, it will work in the following *(commented)*:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_message', 'custom_woocommerce_notice' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_success', 'custom_woocommerce_notice' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice',  'custom_woocommerce_notice' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error',   'custom_woocommerce_notice' );
function custom_woocommerce_notice( $message ) {
    // My Account | Edit password pages
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-password' ) ){
        $message .= ' ' . __('"Edit password" custom message');
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

[image]

Comment: Hey there again loic,, thanks for ther reply, for some reason it left me with this bug, but now i can't seem to revert it back:
The following problems were found:


Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: preg_replace(): Argument #3 ($subject) must be of type array|string, WP_Error given in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/kses.php:1744 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/kses.php(1744): preg_replace() #1 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/kses.php(752): wp_kses_no_null() #2 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-notice-functions.php(287): wp_kses()

Comment: I have recompiled and tested my code… It works, try it.

Comment: Yep, it actually did work but upon refreshing the page, it left me with the bug in a core file kses.php, and even upon removing the new code, the bug it still left in there. Thanks again loic!

Answer (score -2):

Check this

```
function custom_wc_add_notice( $message ){
if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-password' ) ){
    // Add your custom error message here
    $message .= ' Your custom message';
}
return $message;
}

// Hook the custom error message function to the appropriate hooks
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_notice', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_error', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_success', 'custom_wc_add_notice', 10, 1 );
```